# html - What are entities for?

Tags: javascript, html

In HTML, entities such as `&gt;` and `&lt;` are used to type things in HTML like "<b>Hello world!</b>" using `&lt;b&gt;Hello world!&lt;/b&gt;`.

But what is the point of HTML entities? Why isn't it like Javascript where you can just place backslashes in front of `<`, `>`, etc. Like why can't HTML entities be much simpler so that you can type "<b>Hello world!</b>" using `\<b\>Hello world!\</b\>`? Then wouldn't it be more readable with `\<b\>Hello world!\</b\>` instead of `&lt;b&gt;Hello world!&lt;/b&gt;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entities aren't just for escaping special characters. In some settings, you can use entities to transclude snippets of markup.

For example, take a look at how Mozilla has built its error pages:

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/docshell/resources/content/netError.xhtml#348

`&securityOverride.linkText;` is an entity reference. That entity is defined here:

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/locales/en-US/chrome/overrides/netError.dtd#180

In this usage, they've separated the lanuage-dependent strings from the logic and structure of the page, which works well for localization.

In another example, known as the "[billion laughs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs)," a series of entities reference each other in order to produce a billion copies of the word `lol` in just a few lines of code.

Answer (score -2):

If you use the less than (<) or greater than (>) signs in your text, the browser might mix them with tags.

Comment: That's the first sentence of question in another words! It barely answers it.

Comment: Thats the point of using Entities so if your browser might get confused with the > or < symbols you use entities

Comment: Did u read the question?